# Designing a black box python

Tags: python

I want to have a black box in python where

- The input is a list A.
- There is a random number C for the black box which is randomly selected the first time the black box is called and stays the same for the next times the black box is called.
- Based on list A and number C, the output is a list B.

I was thinking of defining this black box as a function but the issue is that a function cannot keep the selected number C for next calls. Note that the input and output of the black box are as described above and we cannot have C also as output and use it for next calls. Any suggestion?

Comment: If this is homework, you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: Why don't you set variale outside of function and every time function is called you check if variable you set outside is empty `''` or `0`. If its none of these then you set it.

Comment: @rahlf23 nothing much. Just trying to model it as a function.

Comment: @ekhumoro No, it is not a homework. Thanks for asking though.

Comment: @Mick_ I didn't get it. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a Class so C will persist.

```
class BlackBox():
    def __init__(self):
        self.C = rand.randint(100)
        etc...
```

*As a side note, using some pretty cool Python functionality...*

You can make objects of this class callable by implementing `__call__()` for your new class.

```
#inside the BlackBox class
def __call__(self, A):
    B = []
    #do something to B with A and self.C
    return B
```

You can then use this in your main code.

```
bb = BlackBox()
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = bb(A)
```

Comment: Oh, this works. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if you need more information. This answer was minimal, but just enough to get the concept across.

Answer (score 4):

> the issue is that a function cannot keep the selected number C for next calls.

This may be true in other languages, but not so in Python. Functions in Python are objects like any other, so you can store things on them. Here's a minimal example of doing so.

```
import random

def this_function_stores_a_value():
    me = this_function_stores_a_value
    if 'value' not in me.__dict__:
        me.value = random.random()
    return me.value
```

This doesn't directly solve your list problem, but it should point you in the right direction.

---

*Side note:* You can also store persistent data in optional arguments, like

```
def this_function_also_stores_a_value(value = random.random()):
    ...
```

I don't, however, recommend this approach because users can tamper with your values by passing an argument explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to store persistent data for a function. They all have their uses, but in general, the ones that come first are useful more often than the ones that come later. (To keep things shorter, I'm solving a slightly simpler problem than the one you asked about, but it should be obvious how to adapt it.)

### Instance attribute

```
class BlackBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.C = rand.randint(100)
    def check(self, guess):
        return (guess - self.C) / abs(guess - self.C)
```

Now you can create one or more `BlackBox()` instances, and each one has its own random number.

### Closure variable

```
def blackbox():
    C = rand.random()
    def check(guess):
        return (guess - C) / abs(guess - C)
    return check
```

Now, you can create one or more `check` functions, and each one has its own random number. (This is dual to the instance variable—that is, it has the same capabilities—but usually one or the other is more readable.)

### Global variable

```
def makeblackbox():
    global C
    C = random.randint(100)
def check(guess):
    return (guess - C) / abs(guess - C)
```

This way, there's only a single blackbox for the entire program. That's usually not as good a design, which is one of the reasons that "globals are bad". Plus, it's polluting the global namespace with a `C` variable that means nothing to anyone but the `check` function, which is another one of the reasons that "globals are bad".

### Function attribute

```
def makeblackbox():
    check.C = random.randint(100)
def check():
    return (guess - check.C) / abs(guess - check.C)
```

This is equivalent to a global in that you can only ever have one black box, but at least the variable is hidden away on the `check` function instead of polluting the global namespace.

### Class attribute

```
class BlackBox:
    C = rand.randint(100)
    @staticmethod
    def check(guess):
        return (guess - BlackBox.C) / abs(guess - BlackBox.C)
```

This is again equivalent to a global variable without polluting the global namespace. But it has a downside over the function attribute—you're creating a class that has no useful instances is often misleading.

### Class attribute 2

```
class BlackBox:
    C = rand.randint(100)
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, guess):
        return (guess - cls.C) / abs(guess - cls.C)
```

This is different from the last three in that you can create new blackboxes by creating subclasses of `BlackBox`. But this is very rarely what you actually want to do. If you want multiple persistent values, you probably want instances.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking in the comments.
This is probably not recommended way but it's easy and works so I'll add it here.

You can use global variable to achieve your goal.

```
import random

persistant_var = 0

def your_func():
    global persistant_var
    if persistant_var:
        print('variable already set {}'.format(persistant_var))
    else: 
        print('setting variable')
        persistant_var = random.randint(1,10)

your_func()
your_func()
```

Output:

```
setting variable
variable already set 7
```

Hope this is clear.

[image]